# suppressing mexPrintf in matlab mex code

Tags: c++, matlab, io, printf, mex

I have mex code that I call from my matlab scripts. To debug the code, I had put a lot of mexPrintf statements, but for timing purposes now I don't want any I/O taking place in my mex code call (since I/O takes a lot of time). What's the easiest and best way to suppress the mexPrintf calls in my code, such that those statements are not executed at all, without having to delete/comment out those statements? (I don't want to delete/comment out those statements and recompile my mex code because I may need these debug statements later on, and I don't want to keep going through this iteration of modifying and building my code again and again).

Is there any compiler switch that can do the trick? or some preprocessor statement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not turn `mexPrintf` off. You need to modify your code. Define e.g. `DEBUG` flag to decide, when you want to print things, and when not. For example, with normal `printf` function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//#define DEBUG
#ifdef DEBUG
#define MPRINT(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__);
#else
#define MPRINT(...)
#endif

int main()
{
  MPRINT("%d\n", 5);
}
```

Nothing is printed if you run it now. But if you uncomment the `#define DEBUG` statement, you get 5 printed.

Alternatively, you can embrace all `mexPrintf` calls in such clauses:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
mexPrintf(...);
#endif
```

Again, nothing will be printed if `DEBUG` is not defined. But that is much more work.

You can also do a similar thing without recompiling your mex file by using a normal `if` statement and pass a `verbose` parameter to the mex file. However, this will still have some impact on performance if you execute the `if` statement too often. So go for the `DEBUG` more - that is the standard way to do it.

Comment: +1 The "#define DEBUG" would be a classic way to do it in C, but it'd probably be more "standard" Matlab style to use the runtime `verbose` flag, so you don't have to recompile the MEX each time you change it. The cost of the extra C function call and `if` check is going to be trivial compared to whatever M work is being done in the function. And you could add a special `mymexfunction('debug','on')` calling form and `static` verbose variable to turn the debug output on or off globally, so you don't have to pass the `verbose` flag at each function call site.

Comment: @AndrewJanke True. Well, I usually combine those. For really uninteresing debugging information I use `ifdef`. For some useful timing information, or model information I use the `verbose` flag.

Comment: Cool. I've ended up leaning the other way: granular runtime config for everything. On a previous project, we built a Matlab logging framework on top of Java SLF4J logging, and it was so useful that I'm biased toward that style of debugging output now. (Especially for large projects that get deployed to other users or server-side, so you can debug without redeploying.) So I'd do that with all runtime tests, using an `int verbose` to define multiple levels of detail instead of just on/off. YMMV.